# Мобильное меню с visibility

Tags: javascript, css, scss, menu, opacity

При появлении во время анимации появляется сначала под контентом, потом всплывает сверху и становится на своё место. [image: По бокам видно это меню, по умолчанию фон страницы А вот момент, когда меню всплываетбелый.]

Хочу сделать, чтобы меню всплывало поверх всеъ элементов. прописывал z-index - не помогает.

В JS меню меняется по visibility от hidden до visible и меняется Opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Ответил на свой вопрос сам - position-absolute не задал менюшке... XD